# UPDATE a table with rows from another table using a CTE

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I need to update a column in all rows in B_solarTypeDB.dbo.spaceList with values from the same column in A_solarTypeDB.dbo.spaceList

I have this CTE below that returns all astroID values from A_solarTypeDB.dbo.spaceList that are not in B_solarTypeDB.dbo.spaceList

Is there a way to do an UPDATE on B_solarTypeDB.dbo.spaceList with those values?

Here is my attempt with a CTE:

```
UPDATE B_solarTypeDB.dbo.spaceList
SET astroID = 
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT astroID FROM A_solarTypeDB.dbo.spaceList
    EXCEPT
    SELECT astroID FROM B_solarTypeDB.dbo.spaceList
)
SELECT astroID 
FROM A_solarTypeDB.dbo.spaceList
WHERE astroID IN (SELECT astroID FROM CTE)
```

But I get a syntax error near ";"

Here is sample data from A_solarTypeDB.dbo.spaceList:

```
spaceID     spaceName    typeID     astroID
2937        Mars         1          9481ffg1
2938        Titan        3          4728ffu3
2939        MG1          7          4937fft5
```

I need to do the update on B_solarTypeDB.dbo.spaceList because sometimes the value for astroID is NULL, when it should be the same as in the A_solarTypeDB database.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact update logic?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks, I forgot to include that.  I've updated the original question to show my attempted `UPDATE` command and the resulting error.

Comment: Sample data would be helpful.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen good idea...:)  done!

Comment: You're using the CTE as if it were a query here. Think of CTEs as subqueries that always appear *before* the query itself. The query itself should start with `WITH myCTE as {} UPDATE`.

Comment: In this particular case though it's cleaner to just use a subquery. Put the UNION query in the `IN ()` clause

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hi , what do you mean by the UNION query?  thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell you really really really shouldn't use names like `typeBdb.dbo.spacelist`. It looks like you're using the same tables everywhere. The single character in the middle of the string is very easy to miss

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that's definately true...I will change the names to make it more obvious :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos should I replace what is currently in the `IN()` clause with the larger query above?  And then delete the original?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it without a CTE like this:

```
    UPDATE typeBdb.dbo.spaceList
    SET astroID = T2.astroID
    FROM
    (
       SELECT astroID,CommonUniqueID
       FROM typeAdb.dbo.spaceList
       WHERE astroID IN 
       (
            SELECT astroID 
            FROM (
                        
                    SELECT astroID FROM typeAdb.dbo.spaceList
                    EXCEPT
                    SELECT astroID FROM typeBdb.dbo.spaceList
                    
               ) T1
    
       )
    ) T2
   WHERE typeBdb.dbo.spaceList.CommonUniqueID = T2.CommonUniqueID
```

Comment: That set the astroID in typeBdb.dbo.spaceList to the same ID in every row

Comment: If there's a common field from typeBdb.dbo.spaceList that you can match with typeAdb.dbo.spaceList you can add WHERE clause at the end to match. I have updated the query above to show how this could work.